# MySQL Selecting hierarchy with union

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

I have hierarchy data like so:

```
Id, Related
1, 0
2, 1
3, 1
4, 1
5, 4
6, 3
7, 0
8, 7
9, 3
10, 8
```

I would like to select select 2 parents and then find 2 children for each of the parents

Result:

```
id
1
  2
  3
7
  8
```

Something like:

```
select * from TABLE T1 where T1.related=0 order by T2.id limit 2 
union 
select * from TABLE T2 where T1.id=T2.related order by T2.id limit 2
```

I've been researching mysql select hierarchical data but I can't find anything to help with my situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. I test it in MSSQl. I hope its also work in mysql**

```
SELECT id,child FROM
(SELECT t1.Related id,t1.id child,row_number() over (partition by t1.Related ORDER BY t1.Id) sl FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.Related=t2.Id) t
where t.sl<=2
```

OR

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @Related:=0;
SET @Child:=0;
SELECT t.id,t.Child FROM 
(SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @Related=t1.Related THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_nu, @Related:=t1.Related AS id,@Child:=t1.id AS Child
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.Related=t2.Id) t
WHERE t.row_nu<=2;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4wJQ4j8PPq5iLnncBXteqL/2)
[upadte DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4wJQ4j8PPq5iLnncBXteqL/4)

Comment: I don't believe that will work in MySQL < 8.0 (still in beta), as window functions don't yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all records with `Related = 0`. Then you want to select up to two random children. One solution is to take the min child ID and the max child ID. You can look up parents in a subquery.

```
select
  related as parent_id, 
  min(id) as child1_id,
  max(id) as child2_id
from mytable
where related in (select id from mytable where related = 0)
group by related;
```

If you don't want to show the same child ID twice (in case of only one child, i.e. `min(id) = max(id)`), change this to:

```
select
  related as parent_id, 
  min(id) as child1_id,
  nullif(max(id), min(id)) as child2_id
...
```

These queries don't show `related = 0` records without children, but well, without children they are not parents anyway :-)

Comment: Interesting but I would like to stay flexible. I would like like row 1 to be a parent, row 2 & 3 to be its children if they exists, next row to be another parent if it exists, and another two children. But I would like to be able to change that to more children in the future.

Comment: This is usually solved with a recursive query. Available as of MySQL 8.0. With a lower MySQL version I would refrain from doing this in SQL and rather do it in the app or Website with a programming language.

Comment: As you are only interested in the top two levels of the tree, this should be possible without a recursive query, though. Probably with MySQL variables.